# Определить состояние чекбокса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть кастомный чекбокс на сайте, по клику на который необходимо узнать активный он или нет.
Пишу следующие:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".style-checkbox", function() {
  console.log($(this).find("input").is(":checked"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="style-checkbox">
        <input class="style-checkbox__input" type="checkbox" name="basket-additional">
        <span class="style-checkbox__newcheck" type="checkbox" name="basket-additional"></span>
        <div class="style-checkbox__name">Какой-то текст</div>
    </label>
```

В результате данного выполнения скрипта в консоле я получаю одновременно false и true, если элемент не активен изначально и наоборот true и false если был изначально активен. Из-за чего появляется этот задубленный вариант, как исправить?

Comment: Не понятен вопрос. Если чекбокс активен, то должно вернуть `true`, если не активен - `false`. В обоих случаях, у Вас, все работает корректно

Comment: У меня ответ выводится одновременно false, true, а надо чтобы одно выводилось либо false, либо true

Comment: Все прекрасно работает...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо обработки клика обрабатывайте изменение состояния инпута, ваша ошибка проявляется из-за очередности вызова событий при клике по тексту.

```js
$(document).on("change", ".style-checkbox__input", function() {
  console.log($(this).is(":checked"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="style-checkbox">
        <input class="style-checkbox__input" type="checkbox" name="basket-additional">
        <span class="style-checkbox__newcheck" type="checkbox" name="basket-additional"></span>
        <div class="style-checkbox__name">Какой-то текст</div>
    </label>
```

Comment: Спасибо то, что нужно!!!